# Where does Scheme store its types?

Tags: scheme

The following throws an error:

```
Chez Scheme Version 9.5.8
Copyright 1984-2022 Cisco Systems, Inc.

> (define-record-type point (fields x y)) 
> point
Exception: invalid syntax point
```

I have specified to define a type called `point`, but it can not be looked up in the environment. If the type is not stored in the environment, where is it stored instead? Is there some hidden meta-environment for types?

Comment: https://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/csug9.5/syntax.html#./syntax:h4 might give some insight about how Chez implements `define-record-type`. (In particular, I bet `point` is a compile time value; using it outside of syntax forms designed to work with it is as you see an error)

Comment: You can use `(record-type-descriptor point)` to get the type descriptor, which can be used to get information about the record.

Comment: @Shawn And how about the builtin types (string, symbol, pair etc.)?

Comment: What about them?

Answer (score 2):

How records are stored is implementation dependent and nothing you need to know to use the feature. Ist's most likely done in syntax expansion and using an already existing type to store the data. Eg. they can use vectors with fields translating to refs within the vector and some index that indicates that it is a record and what kind that both a modified `vector?` and `point?` will check for.

According to the [R6RS](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r6rs/r6rs-lib-std/r6rs-lib-Z-H-7.html#node_chap_6) your expression will make constructor `make-point` and type predicate `point?`. `point` will not be bound to anything unless you specify it explicitly as a constructor:

```
(define-record-type (point point point?)
  (fields 
    (immutable x point-x)
    (immutable y point-y)))
point  ; ==> #<procedure point>
point? ; ==> #<procedure point?>
```

Comment: I am searching for the type itself not the constructor.

Comment: @ceving I'm not sure how many interpreters or compilers you've written, but there are numerous ways to do this. If you're looking for how Chez does it you should look at the [source code](https://github.com/cisco/ChezScheme/tree/main)